# PDF font and Header not showing on load

Tags: media-library

I have one PDF file(Content in chinese) stored in sitecore media library but when i try to view it from website(in chrome and microsoft edge) then at first the header logo and some characters of the pdf do not load. But when i scroll down and then up to top then everything(characters and header logo) show up. i have checked that there is no issue with the pdf file as i tried to download and open that file in same browser and it opens without any issues.

Please let me know if anyone has faced same issue or has solution for it.

Comment: When you browse the pdf file it takes some time to load in memory, if your pdf file size is big then this could be the common case. But you can also check that you have the latest version of PDF reader installed.

Comment: I waited for 2 minutes for the file to load which is of 443 KB but it still behaves the same. when i try to open the same file from my system in same browser then it loads everything instantly.

Comment: Do you use any custom code to output the pdf to users in browser? Anyone else in your team with the same issue?